# automatically change object colors in pymol from python

Tags: python, colors, pymol

I am trying to change the color of many objects in pymol from python. I made this for loop

```
obs = ['R8', 'R1X', 'R2X', 'R11']
for i in obs:
    print "color gray, %s" % i
```

from pymol I run

```
run myscript.py
```

but the pymol interface simply prints the the command that should change the color, and does not change the color of the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute Pymol commands from python you need to use [`cmd`](http://pymol.org/pymol-command-ref.html). In your case this would be:

```
cmd.color('gray', i)
```